Window installation error with linux boot drive
I can't install Windows 11 on my SSD with a GPT partition. I've tried using both Ventoy and Rufus, with and without secure boot, but nothing seems to work. It keeps showing the error:

Windows could not prepare the computer to boot into the next phase of installation." What could be the issue?

